# Bisection index search - why compare to len(a)?

Tags: python, bisection

So I'm trying to understand bisection. I get that it's a useful, computation-saving algorithm, I get the general concept of what it does and how it does it.
What I don't get involves this search function that uses it, taken from https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html

```
from bisect import bisect_left    

def index(a, x):
        'Locate the leftmost value exactly equal to x'
        i = bisect_left(a, x)
        if i != len(a) and a[i] == x:
            return i
        raise ValueError
```

Could somebody please break down for me exactly what the **i != len(a)** part of the if line does? I can read it - it checks whether the insertion index of x is equivalent to the length of the list a - but I can't understand it. Why is it necessary? What would happen without it?

I follow that, let's say x has an insertion index greater than the length of a, then x obviously doesn't exist in a so it spews out the error - but if that's the case then the **a[i] == x** check trips it up anyway...?

Thanks!

Comment: To avoid an index error i,e`[1,2,3][3]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since lists are indexed from `0` then `a[i]` doesn't make sense for `i == len(a)` (the last element has index `len(a) - 1`). Doing `a[i]` for such `i` will throw an `IndexError`.

Now if `bisect_left(a, x)` returns `len(a)` then it means that the element should be added *at the end* of the list in order to preserve the order.

On the other hand if there is a match for `x` in `a` then

```
bisect_left(a, x) != len(a)
```

because `If x is already present in a, the insertion point will be before (to the left of) any existing entries`. If it is *before* then obviously the insertion index has to be smaller or equal to the last index (since in worst case this *matched* element will have last index) and the last index is `len(a)-1` which is smaller then the length.

All in all if `bisect_left(a, x) == len(a)` then there is no `x` in `a`. This allows us to easily get rid of "`IndexError` problem" that I've mentioned at the begining.

Note that this (obviously) is not true for `bisect_right`. However following similar logic you can reach something analogous: if `bisect_right(a, x) == 0` then there is no `x` in `a`. Unfortunately implementing `index` function via `bisect_right` would be more difficult since you would still need this check for `i == len(a)` to avoid an `IndexError`.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. So, what's so bad about the IndexError in this situation then? This function raises an error anyway if x isn't in a, so both outcomes let me know that no, x isn't in a?

Comment: @Plebas_The_Seabass Changing the type of error that the function raises allows for better semantics to the caller. What I mean is that the function as defined raises a `ValueError` whenever you pass a value to `index` that isn't in the list. Allowing an `IndexError` to raise in this case wouldn't make much sense semantically; those are reserved for when the caller supplies an index that is out of bounds.

Comment: Right so because we're trying to find out "is x a value in the current list" rather than "is x outside the current list", the name of the error just helps to make the result...clearer?

Comment: @Phlebas_The_Seabass `IndexError` is used when index is involved. If you treat the function as a blackbox (i.e. without looking at the implementation) then no index is used at all. It would be very unexpected to see index error being thrown. Plus inconsistent with `.index()` method on lists. Note that as it is you can replace `a.index(x)` method with `index(a, x)` function anytime you won't. But that would be impossible if `index(a, x)` were to throw `IndexError` in some cases. So all in all it's more like following a standard.

Answer (score 0):

Zero based indexing. The `i != len(a)` is to catch the exact case where `i` is equal to the length of the list, in which case `a[i]` will raise an index error (lists start at index 0 and go up to `len(a) - 1`).

Comment: Thanks, this helped.